# For a two-level atom subject to a laser field, what is the rate of absorption followed by stimulated emission?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, atomic-physics, laser

So the textbook I'm using (H.J. Metcalf and P. van der Straten. Laser Cooling and Trapping)
derives the photon scattering rate of a laser close to a two-level transition starting from the Optical Bloch Equations. A short open-access summary can be found [here](http://info.phys.unm.edu/%7Eideutsch/Classes/Phys500S09/Downloads/handpubl.pdf) (eq.2):

$$\gamma_p = \frac{s_0 \gamma/2}{1+s_0 + [2(\delta + \omega_D)/\gamma]^2}$$

Where $\gamma_p$ is the photon scattering rate, $\gamma$ the natural linewidth, $s_0 = I/I_{sat}$ the saturation intensity normalized to the saturation intensity, $\delta$ the laser detuning and $\omega_D$ the frequency doppler shift.

It is my understanding that this is the rate of spontaneous emission. I'm wondering if there is a similar equation which gives the rate of absorption followed by stimulated emission, i.e. where "nothing happens" to the atom? Or in the context of linewidth-broadening, what is the fraction of stimulated emission to spontaneous emission?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [the Rabi cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_cycle)?

Comment: Yes, but specifically for absorption of a photon by an atomic transition